# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application' when deploying Flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been struggling with an ostensibly simple error while trying to deploy a Flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk for quite some time now. Launching the app gives a `502 Bad Gateway` error. The traceback in the logs reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
worker.init_process()
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
super().init_process()
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
self.load_wsgi()
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
self.callable = self.load()
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
mod = importlib.import_module(module)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
```

My flask app, in `application.py`, is as simple as it gets:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

application = app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()

@application.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', name=None)
```

As is my directory structure. I upload `ball.zip` which contains:

```
ball/
    application.py
    requirements.txt
    static/
    templates/
```

The application is using Python 3.7 run on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.9. I've also checked that the configuration variable `WSGIPath` is set to `application`. Does anyone have any pointers on fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have folder "ball" in your zip. Every file should be in the root of the zip, not in the folder "ball".

Comment: Thanks. It's not so much that "ball" is in the zip, but rather that the directory "ball" is the zipped directory. Is this still incorrect?

Comment: @Toby With your setup there shouldn't be any folder. Your flask should be in `application.py`, not in `ball/application.py`

Comment: Ah I see now. Just pushed that change and it finally worked! Thanks!